# extract columns from different tables and display next to each other

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to pull columns from two different tables next to each other.

I have php code as below :

```
<table>
 <tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Performance A </th>
<th>Performance B </th>
</tr>
$sql = "select date, Aperformance from table1 group by date";
$sql1 = "select date, Bperformance from table2 group by date";
$result = mssql_query($sql);
while ($column = mssql_fetch_array($result))

{
echo "<tr><td>".$column[0]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$column[1]."</td></tr>";
}
```

And this produces output as below :

```
 Date     | Performance A | Performance B
 01/05/12 | 40%           | 
 02/05/12 | 30%           |
 03/05/12 | 25%           |
```

Now I want to fill up the third column from query $sql1. I don't want date column from $sql1, the second column Bperformance needs to put in here. How I can do that?

Comment: fyi: If a query doesn't specify an `ORDER BY` clause, then there is no guarantee of the order of rows returned.  Placing the results of two queries side-by-side and hoping that they have a column in common may result in consternation.  Using a `JOIN` will ensure that the data are correlated, but the order still must be specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both queries return the same number of rows, you could simply do:

```
$result1 = mssql_query($sql);
$result2 = mssql_query($sql2);
while($column1 = mssql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $column2 = mssql_fetch_array($result2);
    echo "<tr><td>$column1[0]</td><td>$column2[0]</td></tr>";
}
```

If the queries return different sized result sets, then you'll have do some extra work.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a join, using a full outer join allows you to retrieve the rows if there is no date matching in one of the table

```
SELECT A.Date , A.APerformance AS [Performance A] , B.BPerformance AS [Performance B]
FROM (
    SELECT Date
        ,APerformance
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Date
    ) A
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT Date
        ,BPerformance
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY Date
    ) B ON A.Date= B.Date
```

Comment: @user1449596 It's safer to use this one because of the limitations of the previous query ( as marc pointed out ). IMO it's also better to run the whole thing in one query call instead of two calls